# What sequence of moves in Solo Caverna result in the maximum score?

Tags: caverna

The solo game of Caverna is completely deterministic.  There is no luck.  There are no opponents to mess up your strategy.  So, a particular sequence of moves will always result in the same score.

Which means that there is a particular sequence of moves that will result in the maximum possible score.

Now, I'm not actually expecting anyone to put forth each and every choice that you would have to make--though that would be very cool.  As a computer geek, I've spent a few minutes musing about how to design a program that will do the search; but, I'd rather spend my time playing Caverna than to write such a simulator.

But, surely there are some good Solo Caverna players out there, who could at least talk about their particular strategies for maximizing points.  Are there particular furnishings that you get?  Ruby maximization?  Weapons?  6 Dwarfs?  What do you do that breaks the "magical 100 point mark?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to maximum points for my solo endeavours has been to use the Office which allows overhangs, and the Guest room for multiple actions.  I then work to get many tunnels inside, and overhang tunnels.  After the overhang tunnels are placed, I also place Ore mines, for even more overhang bonus, and use the double action to place two ruby mines at once.  For this to work, you need extra dwarfs, preferably 5.  You should be pulling in about 30ish gold.

All in all, because of the possibility of a 'optimal' strategy based on card layout, I also tend to use some dice to add some random blocking, so the game has some more replay-ability solo.

I usually score around 140.

Comment: So, what kind of scores do you generally get with this strategy?

Comment: Apparently this is now illegal.  You can't place deep mines or pastures as overhangs, and you get no bonus gold for placing them already overhanging tiles.

Answer (score 3):

I am not going to duplicate the text here, but there is a walkthrough for a 200 point game here: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1187325/real-magical-score-solo-game-200-points

Answer (score 2):

In an effort to analyze how to get 6 dwarves on the 7th turn, using office room to net ~24 coins, guest room to net ~6 free actions, and primarily banking on furnishings for points (state parlor: 16, food chamber: 12, main storage: 12, broom chamber: 10, treasure chamber: 8, beer parlor: 7), I was able to attain 156.

6 points (1 dwarf + 5 broom) + 4 actions (averaging 5-6 points) seem to certainly make the 6th dwarf worth getting. Basically trading 16 resources and action for ~33 points.

might be able to push it higher by replacing beer parlor and one of the mines with a better food engine/farming/animals.

Final board state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9sfI.jpg